# Recursion for Decision Tree based form

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have been working on a decision tree based form.  The form consists of pages of four questions with predetermined choices to answer. Each page can have one question that branches out to a new branch of questions.  Pages are in the form of a div with data attributes for the name of the branch and the page number (data-branch="whatever" and data-page-number="1")  When a user answers a question that sends them to a new branch, a nextBranch variable is set and when all four questions have been answered the branch name and page number values are added to a log and a next() method is called.  This method figures out the next page based on the nextBranch variable and the last entry in the log (branch name and page number).

If the nextBranch is not equal to the currentBranch, the user is taken to first page of the nextBranch, but if the nextBranch is equal to the currentBranch, the pageNumber is incremented and the user is taken to next page in the current branch. If no results are found I call a method that loops through the page log in reverse until the branch value in the iteration is different to the currentBranch value. When those values don't match, I increment the pageNumber from the current iteration and look for that page.

This approach works fine when I just branch off the original branch, but when I branch off a branch, looping over the log in reverse no longer works.

Lets say I have the tree structure below, I start at A1 and answer the questions that lead me to C2, my log will look like this:

```
[{'A': '1'},{'A': '2'},{'A': '3'},{'B': '1'},{'B': '2'},{'C': '1'},{'C': '2'}]
```

When reach C2, since the is no C3, I loop through the log in reverse, the first item I reach whose branch name is not equal to the last entry is B2, so incrementing the page number returns B3, which is valid. Now the log looks like this

```
[{'A': '1'},{'A': '2'},{'A': '3'},{'B': '1'},{'B': '2'},{'C': '1'},{'C': '2'},{'B: '3'}]
```

After finishing B3 I loop through the log in reverse again, the first item I reach whose branch name is not equal to the last entry is C2 - incrementing the page here returns C3 when it should actually return A4...

I am struggling to find a solution with the current way this is set up so I would love any suggestions!!

Here is a fiddle of what I currently have - https://jsfiddle.net/yphyk3sq/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the log needs to preserve all the page views, so probably searching the log isn't the thing to do.

Instead you could create a stack specifically for this reverse search.  Whenever the branch ID changes, you push the old ID onto the stack.  When you run out of C pages, you look at the stack and see that B is the previous, so you pop B and continue with the next B page.  When you run out of B pages, the top of the stack will be A and you move along as intended.

Comment: Sometimes you just need a 2nd pair of eyes. Makes perfect sense to log (in this example) A3, B2 and C2 then pop the stack when there are no more pages in the current branch.